# Android: Use Google API for Real-time directions, or Communicate with Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps

I know this question has been asked before, but I could not find a satisfactory answer: Is it possible to get Real-Time Direction updates from the Google API available to Android. The Google Maps API only provides the visual functionality, but not any directional capability. The Google Directions API is not meant to be used for real-time direction. Is there anything that could be used in this capacity, or should I try instead to communicate with the Android Google Maps app and gather directions through that?

Answer (score 1):

@Benjamin, I think it is not possible; in the [Google Maps/Google Earth APIs Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#10-license-restrictions) under:

> **10.4 Restrictions on Unfair Exploitation of the Service and Content**
>
> c.Restrictions on your Maps API Implementations.
>
> iii.No navigation. You will not use the Service or Content for or in connection with (a) *real-time navigation or route guidance*; or (b) automatic or autonomous vehicle control.