# Google Maps avoiding tolls, highways or ferries in turn by turn navigation intent

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, parameters

I am using Google Maps turn by turn navigation in my app to navigate from the current location to a given address. It works fine, my only problem is that I cannot set up avoid tolls/highways/ferries options via intent.

I followed google descriptions here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents#launch_turn-by-turn_navigation

My code is the following with avoid tolls parameter:

```
String navigation = "google.navigation:q=" + latLng.latitude + "," + latLng.longitude + "&avoid=t";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(navigation);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(intent);
```

Navigation starts fine, but it doesn't take notice of the avoid tolls parameter, it opens the driving route through roads, where tolls must be paid.

I also tried &dirflg=t and &avoid=tolls parameters, but no result.

Does anybody have some solution for this?
Thank you!

Comment: UPDATE: It works on API 21, but still NOT works on API 17 device.
But I cannot find any descrition about the minimum system requirement of this option. Does anybody have some idea how could I find this out?

Comment: Maybe the problem is in how you set your code, try to follow the exact code on the given [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents#launch_turn-by-turn_navigation). Provide some address and copy the same format of the code. Now, check if the avoid parameter is working. Check also this [ticket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36905919/android-use-google-api-for-real-time-directions-or-communicate-with-google-map) about the turn by turn navigation service.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but unfortunately this didn't solve my problem. I added now the destination address in the same format as it is written in the documentation, but it also returned with a route on highways.
Anyway, I tried my original code also on an API 19 device, and it works, so I can solve it by raising the minimum API to 19 from 17 (it is not a big problem, I think) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a bug in some of the android implementations on some devices.
I have the same problem. The same code runs fine on an A3 (2016), but not on an Xcover 3. Both on Lollipop (API 22) but on slightly different versions (newer on the A3). Maybe an update will help.