# Gps Navigation Example Android JAVA

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation, gps

I want to make a navigation system. like when i need turn left to go my home , my navigation is saying to me "Turn Left" . Do any source for this example or can anyone help me for this ?

Comment: You may wish to review the terms of service of your map engine (e.g., Maps V2 for Android) and perhaps discuss those terms of service with your attorney. What you want to do may not be allowed under those terms of service.

Comment: Backing up CommonsWare's comment, you can look at the Google Maps/Google Earth APIs Terms of Service on Restrictions on Unfair Exploitation of the Service and Content. See my answer in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36934942/5995040)

Comment: ups.. i think this is very hard...

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a service like mapquest.
It's fairly easy to parse the return,  you have a series of way points you can plot and when the GPS distance to that way point is less than x meters then read the announcement and start monitoring the proximity of the next one.